# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.clearCache()V

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I am getting the above error. After googling a bit, I came to know that the problem is with the dependencies. So I ran mvn dependency:tree command and got the following output -

> `INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ dubbo-test ---
>   [INFO] com.privacera.dubbo:dubbo-test:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
>   [INFO] +- com.alibaba.boot:dubbo-spring-boot-starter:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
>   [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE:true
>   [INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE:runtime
>   [INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.3:runtime
>   [INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.3:runtime
>   [INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.13:runtime
>   [INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.13:runtime
>   [INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.13:runtime
>   [INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.16:runtime
>   [INFO] |  +- com.alibaba:dubbo:jar:2.5.9:compile
>   [INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.20.0-GA:compile
>   [INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.netty:netty:jar:3.2.5.Final:compile
>   [INFO] |  +- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.9:compile
>   [INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile
>   [INFO] |  |  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:compile
>   [INFO] |  |  +- jline:jline:jar:0.9.94:compile
>   [INFO] |  |  \- io.netty:netty:jar:3.10.5.Final:compile
>   [INFO] |  +- org.apache.curator:curator-framework:jar:2.12.0:compile
>   [INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.curator:curator-client:jar:2.12.0:compile
>   [INFO] |  |     \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:16.0.1:compile
>   [INFO] |  +- com.alibaba.boot:dubbo-spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
>   [INFO] |  \- com.alibaba.boot:dubbo-spring-boot-actuator:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
>   [INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.3.3.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO]    \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.3.3.RELEASE:compile`

But I am unable to understand which dependency is conflicting. Following is the content of my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.vector.dubbo</groupId>
    <artifactId>dubbo-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>dubbo-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I can see is that there are 2 spring boot versions 1.3.3 and 1.3.0(coming from alibaba starter).
Exclude any one of them and try again.
Hope this solves your issue.